# A recent 'react-admin' update moved 'title' into the 'appbar' - how do I push it back into the content?

Tags: appbar, react-admin

With release v2.3.0 the title was moved into the appbar. I want it in the content, and to maintain the app name in the appbar. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

I solved this by creating a custom logo element that I set in each action:

```
// In appTitle.js
import React from 'react';

const AppTitle = () => (
  <a href='http://localhost:3000/#/'>
    <p>YOUR_APP'S_TITLE</p>
  </a>  
);

export default AppTitle;
```

Then import this to your components list and use it as follows:

```
// In your posts.js for example  
import AppTitle from '../appTitle';

export const PostList = (props) => (  
  <List {...props} title={<AppTitle/>}>  
    ...
```

Doing this for all of your actions (Edit, Show, Create) for each entity.

Of course you can create your own custom appbar but I chose this option as simpler.

If you want your title for the current post (in example) to be shown, you can display it within the list as a `<TextField source="title"/>`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Sheesh, what a pain. Seems like a lot of work-around to do a standard thing. I still don't see how to have the 'title' in the post itself. Sure, I can list a field called 'title', but that's not a page title. It sounds like this means I've got to use the controllers(i.e. ListController) directly and add my own header.